# Can we say, "People should be made admire the winners"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

We can say: "I'll make the people admire the winners", but can we make it in passive voice? Is it possible to say:"People should be made admire the winners"?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it's possible to say it, but it's not good syntax.  "People should be made **to** admire the winners" is valid syntax, but I'm not sure it's the meaning you wish to put across.

Comment: The best place to ask these basic questions is at our sister site *English Language Learners* ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think it's correct to use, "make + sb + to + infinitive", can we? As I know that it is a causative verb, isn't it?

Comment: The verb "be made" (in the sense of being coerced) virtually demands to be followed by a prepositional phrase beginning with "to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the norm:

> I'll force (the)  people **to** admire the winners.
>   I'll encourage
>   people **to** admire the winners.
>   I'll persuade people **to** admire
>   the winners.

but **'make'** is an exception:

> I'll make (the) people admire the winners.

but in the passive they all take **to** + vb:

> People should be **forced to** admire the winners
>   People should be **encouraged** **to** admire the winners
>   People should be **made to** admire the winners